# Eclipse editor allows for lack of static and final keywords in interfaces

Tags: java, eclipse, interface

I was testing if I could set a non static, non final field in a Java interface. I was surprised to see that while writing the program in Eclipse, it did not complain if I created an interface like the one below. It even compiles and runs:

```
public interface Interface
{
    public String nonStaticField = "Not static";
}
```

Of course, it prevented me from changing the value of the field in the main method. However I would like to know if the reason the compiler allows for the absence of the static and final words is because they're implicit, or if there's any usage for this syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.3) itself:

> Every field declaration in the body of an interface is implicitly public, static, and final. It is permitted to redundantly specify any or all of these modifiers for such fields.

So yeah, it is implicit and you are allowed not to specify any of them because a field inside an interface must be final and static.